# WordPress : Remove page title with filter in function.php

Tags: wordpress, filter, page-title

I want not to display page title for specific page. How can be this with filter in function.php?

Answer (score 2):

within your template files, open page.php

find:

```
<?php the_title();?>
```

change to:

```
<?php
if(is_page('Your-Page-Name')){
   //dont show title
}else{
   the_title();
}
?>
```

so on the page in question, there will be no title shown
but on other pages the other page title will be shown